# Gmail as postfix SMTP relay in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, email, centos, gmail, smtp

Followed these instructions: http://charlesauer.net/tutorials/centos/postfix-as-gmail-relay-centos.php

And still having trouble. Everytime I send a test message, `/var/log/maillog` still returns:

```
postfix/smtp[31970]: 7880343D513C: SASL authentication failed; server smtp.gmail.com[74.125.22.108] said: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsS?534-5.7.14 SVSFq7E-OTTONQlngmEb_fm4fRMazei637OGMU4Kq2MXKcF0YWxX0rtwtXGsGjCywTNu_a?534-5.7.14 1y4zA0I0b3XAMM6zPiTef2Ob4Pk1KpBXT0NvqW2vVV5Y3-BJliImFGtngnAI0d2Dcyuua9?534-5.7.14 Y7Myd-hNV5QxUWrLytnHI4FQmQuU91MYI-AkVNqTF_JZGBuVX236dDoRt_i42DQPnFdlyB?534-5.7.14 WWXVYStViTgACtoFs_7sWtmhI168s> Please log in via your web browser and?534-5.7.14 then try again.?534-5.7.14  Learn more at?534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 q190sm2001023qhb.9 - gsmtp
```

I'm stuck. What else can I try to get SASL to work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this, for anybody else who runs into it: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

You'll need to allow less secure applications to be able to connect to the mail account *explicitly* by going to [the less secure apps page for your account](http://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and next to Access for less secure apps, select turn on.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/662568/why-does-gmail-block-my-postfix-relay